# How to correctly login into xmpp server with libjingle

Tags: c++, authentication, xmpp, libjingle

I have a piece of code, quite basic, for logging in into an xmpp server in libjingle.

I cannot log in into the server. I am sure that the parameters are correct since I checked with an xmpp client program.

My sequence is like this:

1. Create `XmppPump`.
2. Setup callback for `xmppPump.client().SignalStateChange`, which should be called when progress is done through the different states in `XmppEngine`.
3. Start the signaling thread and block on a future that will be unblocked when `XmppPump::DoLogin` is done.

---

```
buzz::XmppClient * xmppClient = mI->xmppPump.client();
assert(xmppClient != nullptr);

buzz::Jid jid = buzz::Jid(user);
std::string server = serverHost + ":" +
   std::to_string(kXmppClientDefaultPort);
bool allow_plain = true;

buzz::XmppClientSettings xcs;
xcs.set_user(jid.node());
xcs.set_resource(jid.resource());
xcs.set_host(jid.domain());
xcs.set_allow_plain(allow_plain);
xcs.set_use_tls(buzz::TLS_DISABLED);
talk_base::InsecureCryptStringImpl pass;
pass.password() = password;
xcs.set_pass(talk_base::CryptString(pass));
std::string server_;
int port;
std::size_t colon = server.find(':');
if (colon == std::string::npos) {
    server_ = server;
    port = kXmppClientDefaultPort;
}
else {
    server_ = server.substr(0, colon);
    port = atoi(server.substr(colon + 1).c_str());
}

std::cout << "Logging in as user " << jid.node() << std::endl;
std::cout << "User domain is " << jid.domain() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Resource is " << jid.resource() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Password is " << password << std::endl;
std::cout << "Logging into server " << server_;
std::cout << " port " << port << std::endl;

xcs.set_server(talk_base::SocketAddress(server_, port));
xcs.set_protocol(cricket::PROTO_SSLTCP);

talk_base::InitializeSSL();

std::future<buzz::XmppEngine::State> result =
   mI->xmppLoginState.get_future();

//Callback is setup here

xmppClient->SignalStateChange.connect(mI.get(),
                                           &Impl::OnStateChange);

std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "About to call buzz::XmppPump::DoLogin " << std::endl;

//Logging in async.
mI->xmppPump.DoLogin(xcs, new buzz::XmppSocket(buzz::TLS_DISABLED), nullptr);

std::cout << "Called buzz::XmppPump::DoLogin " << std::endl;

mI->signalingThread.Start();
std::cout << "Blocked waiting for buzz::xmppPump::DoLogin to finish."
          << std::endl;

//Forever here and XmppEngine::STATE_STARTED always.
result.get();
std::cout << "buzz::XmppPump::DoLogin finished.";
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why the code looks so terrible, I cannot fix it. I did the same thing as always but copy/pasting. Anyone knows the reason so that I can fix it? I left 4 spaces

Comment: Apparently the Markdown parser thinks that your code is part of the numbered list since it's indented.  I "fixed" it by adding a horizontal line.